error: 'cudaDriverEntryPointQueryResult' was not declared in this scope
On my CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 11.7.64  & I am importing both cuda_runtime_api.h as well as cuda_runtime.h but this error still persists.Any workarounds?
I am trying to compile an OS project with GPU support. One of the files in that project was trying to use this function. Other .cu files seem to be compiling fine, so I doubt my cuda compiler is faulty. I checked the runtime api documentation and these functions seem to be available in the version I am using. Not sure what i should update/change.

"I checked the runtime api documentation and these functions seem to be available in the version I am using. "  That enum type is not available in CUDA 11.7.  The first version where cudaDriverEntryPointQueryResult appears to be defined is CUDA 12.0

@RobertCrovella oh is that the case, thanks for sharing! Appreciate it.
